# Adding header to a .doc

Tags: .net, ms-office, document

I need to add an header to a word document previously generated by a component that convert html to rtf (SautinSoft). This component does not support `thead { display: table-header-group; }`. Without using COM, is there a way to achieve this in .NET?

Comment: Do you mean a page header or a table header? Anyway, without COM what you could do is parse and modify the RTF yourself...

Comment: A page header, starting on page 2. I forgot to add that even if the component is called HtmlToRtf, the ouput we got is a .doc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. HTML-to-RTF Pro DLL .Net of SautinSoft support adding an header or a footer :

```
htr.Header.Html(htmlHeader);
htr.Header.Rtf(rtfHeader);
```